# Cannot get ajax to work codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the ajax code

```
      $.ajax({
     url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>deleteRowUsingApiKey/index', //This is the current doc
     type: "POST",
     //dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
     data: {name: '145'},
     success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
         alert(data);
     }
});
```

In the php controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
class DeleteRowUsingApiKey extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
            echo json_encode('test');

    }
}
```

I wanna get the value 'test' in the javascript.But i cant get this working

Comment: `'<?php echo base_url(); ?>deleteRowUsingApiKey/index'`

Comment: @KrishR No still its not working :(

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: its embedded in an html by <script></script>

Comment: and `echo json_encode(array('status'=>'test'));` and in javascript `console.log(data.status);`

Comment: Can you post what you are getting when you do `alert('<?php echo base_url(); ?>deleteRowUsingApiKey/index')`

Comment: I'm thinking you need to use `site_url()` instead of `base_url()`. Do confirm the url.

Answer (score 0):

I guess following code will help you

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
class DeleteRowUsingApiKey extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
           //get data from ajax
           //if you send request with post
           $name = $this->input->post('name');

           //if you send request with get
           $name = $this->input->get('name');

           // create bject for returning data
           $return = array();
           $return['status'] = 'OK';
           $return['msg']    = 'some_message';      


           $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode($return));

    }
}
```

the code must be in server side

Answer (score 0):

Have you included a jquery library? something like

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'); ?  >"></script>
```